# SharePoint Online File and Page Usage Statistics

Tags: sharepoint-online

Please share some inputs on what are the best available options to get Sharepoint Online file and Page usage statistics?
I receive frequent requests from Site Owners to know how they can get a consolidated view of of the number of page visits/views, who all viewed a particular document/downloaded a particular file etc.

Right now we generate audit log reports and tweak the downloaded raw data to get the numbers which is very cumbersome. I am sure there are some products available in market but our organization is not ready to invest.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more detailed reports in the O365 Security and Compliance center. If you visit this page: https://protection.office.com/unifiedauditlog

There you will be able to get reports such as page views by users, document views by users, you will also be able to filter based on a specific site collection or through all sites collections.